# if we have 2 classes child:parent, whats is the difference between

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

in C#
if we have 2 classes child:parent, whats is the difference between:

`parent p = new parent;`
`parent p = new child;`
 `child c = new parent;`

Comment: I have no idea what you talking about. Can you please show minimal but complete, verifiable program demonstrating your problem?

Comment: I know that when we want to create new object we used to do the following:
'parent p = new parent;'
class+name of object= new+class
but I see in somewhere that the class which used to determine the type of object is not the same the class after new but there inheritance between them
@SonerGönül

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep

So, if **class Parent{}** and **class Child : Parent {}**

1) Parent p1 = new Parent(); // creates a new Parent
2) Child c1 = new Child(); // creates a child
3) Parent p2 = new Child(); // creates a child and converts it into a Parent, removing any and every method/property that Parent does not have
4) Child c2 = new Parent(); // will not compile, cannot be implicitly converted

Comment: thanks a lot .. but why may we need Parent p2 = new Child(); ??

Comment: @MostafaShouman because you may have a List<Parent> to add different classes that inherit from Parent

Comment: Use of Parent p2 = new Child();  
It is one of the form of Polymorphism. Consider this example 

class Person
{
void MethodPerson() {}
void Methodcommon() {}
}
class Student : Person
{
void MethodStudent() {}
void Methodcommon() {}
}
Person p1=new Student();
 
basically it forms IS-A relationship between Parent child. so it means
Student IS-A Person. So The new object p1 is a person and will have methodperson and methodcommon(of parent) 
but it will remove methodstudent because it's not there in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you are asking about the effects of polymorphism... In which case

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public class Parent 
    {
        public override string ToString() 
        {
            return "I AM THE PARENT";
        }   
    }

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public override string ToString() 
        {
            return "I AM THE CHILD";
        }   
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Parent parent = new Parent(); 
        Parent pAsChild = new Child();  
        //Child child = new Parent(); does not compile

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", parent.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", pAsChild.ToString());
    }
}
```

you can [play with this on dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/falnWN)

It outputs

```
I AM THE PARENT 
I AM THE CHILD
```